# Mongoose $pull code runs infinitely

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My code runs again and again on a interval of 60 seconds to 2 minutes. This put function needs to be able to dynamically pull data from multiple arrays. I've narrowed it down to only happening on the server side, the function on the client side never fires, but server side will continue to run. Anyone know why this might be happening? I tried 'update', 'findByIdAndUpdate', and 'findById' all with the same result.

```
router.put('/updateDeleteProducts', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("Here is the delete info: ", req.body);

    var size = req.body.size;
    var pictures = req.body.picture;
    var outerfabric = req.body.outerfabric;
    var innerfabric = req.body.innerfabric;
    var armlength = req.body.armlength;
    var backlength = req.body.backlength;

    var updates = {
        $pull: {updated:true}
    };

    if (req.body.size != undefined){
        updates.$pull.size = size;
    }
    if (req.body.picture != undefined){
        updates.$pull.pictures = pictures;
    }
    if (req.body.outerfabric != undefined){
        updates.$pull.outerfabric = outerfabric;
    }
    if (req.body.innerfabric != undefined){
        updates.$pull.innerfabric = innerfabric;
    }
    if (req.body.armlength != undefined){
        updates.$pull.armlength = armlength;
    }
    if (req.body.backlength != undefined){
        updates.$pull.backlength = backlength;
    }

    console.log("Here are the variables to be deleted: ", updates);
    Products.update({_id: req.body._id}, updates, function(err, data){
                if (err) next(err);
                console.log("DELETE Callback Data: ",data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not ending your response. Since you're using express, you should call `res.send()` (or other method that calls the `end` event on your response) inside the `Products.update` callback. Try this:

```
Products.update({_id: req.body._id}, updates, function(err, data){
    if (err) next(err);
    console.log("DELETE Callback Data: ",data);
    res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: Wow.... ya that was stupid. Thanks for the answer, I had a couple other people look at it and we couldn't figure it out.